# Calling a COM function with System.Type parameter from VBA

Tags: c#, vba, com, system.type

I developped an API using C# .NET in which there's a function with a "System.Type" as parameter : "public string MyFunction(System.Type myType) { ... }"

This function is COM visible.

In an Excel workbook, I reference the API (MyApi) and I want to call this function but I don't find any way to do so.
Is it possible ?

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim t As String
    t = MyApi.MyFunction(???)
End Sub
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: System.Type is [ComVisible] as well, you can add a reference to mscorlib.tlb.  How you expect the VBA programmer to obtain the correct type to pass is exceedingly murky.